# Spring: redirect from POST method doesn't work

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, postman

I'm trying to get my Spring controller recieve POST request. I want to get the body of post request and show it on web page. I send requests via Postman. My controller receives it, but somehow, when I try to redirect to another page as usual, Spring renders the html template and sends it back to Postman.

My code:

```
@GetMapping("/webhooks")
public String webhooks(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("response", "webhooks");
    return "connected";

@PostMapping("/webhooks")
public String webhooks(String payload, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("response", payload);
    return "connected";
}
```

My connected.html template:

```
<body>
<a href="/" >Home</a>
<h3>Connected!</h3>
<div>
  <button onclick="refreshToken()">Refresh Token</button>
  <br /><br />
  <button onclick="newCustomer()">Create new customer</button>
  <button onclick="invoice()">Create new invoice</button>
  <br />
  <div><code id="result" th:text="${response}"></code></div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is what I see in Postman window:
[image: link to image]

But I expect to see the same form (as on the picture) in my browser and not in Postman. I want to redirect to this page and not to send this page back to Postman. I have a few similar methods in other controllers which are completely identical, but they work correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *and show the body of the request on the page* What doe this mean? *But I expect to see the same form in my browser and not in Postman.* What does this mean. Clarify exactly what you mean here because it is unclear. What exactly is it you expect to see in Pstman?

Comment: @AlanHay I've edited the question. Actually, you can just look at the picture to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I am confused. You send a request via postman but want the result to be displayed in the browser?

Comment: @AlanHay I send request to my application. I want to show the body of the request in browser, I mean, send it to html template and open this page in browser. I'm trying to redirect to '/connected' page, but instead of redirecting Spring sends this page back to Postman. How do I properly redirect to '/connected'?

Comment: why you are relating things- postman and browser at the same time?

Comment: @LizaChigrina, I can see everything is ok. you just need to test it from browser perspective and you will get what you want.

Comment: @user404 I understand this. If post request comes from some server, identical answer with rendered template is send to that server. In any case it doesn't redirect, it sends my complete connected.html page back to some server, and I want to redirect to this page.

Comment: @LizaChigrina It's unclear what are you trying to achieve. The code working as it should be. If a http request is send from a client the response will be sent to the same client (in your case postman), you cannot set the response to a different client (such as browser).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you have, I tried different ways to fix this problem but none of them worked for me. But you could give it a try:

```java
@GetMapping("/webhooks")
public RedirectView webhooks(Model model) {
    //Do what you want
    return new RedirectView("/connected");

@PostMapping("/webhooks")
public RedirectView webhooks(String payload, Model model) {
    //Do what you want
    return new RedirectView("/connected");
}
```

This didn't work out for me but it might help you out. You use the RedirectView class from Spring and enter the URL to the endpoint.

Please let me know if it worked for you!